# Crystal report not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

```
OS details: Windows 8 64 bit

Visual studio: 2012

Crystal Report Version : 13_0_2
```

till now,I was using `XP SP3 [32 bit]` with `VS2010`,and crystal report was working properly.But now, after upgrade, when I click `ADD ITEMS` in aspx page,the list of contents doesn't show me crystal report.

In toolbox also,no crystal report controls were available.

I have installed it twice,but still not getting crystal report components.

Answer (score 1):

To work with Visual Studio 2012 you need SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio - Service Pack 6 or higher.

See [this](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) for a quick look-up of all Support Packs, Fixed Issues and Distribution File downloads available for SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio.